# Provided header file does not #include <string> & not allowed to alter. How can I include it in my cpp file?

Tags: c++, string, header, include

For my current class project, we were provided the following header file that we are not allowed to alter. It does not include guards or any include statements, including iostream or string, which are needed and throw the error "std::string has not been declared" when the program is run. Is there a way to include it in my cpp file instead? I've been hunting for a solution, but everything I have come across says just to include it in the header file. I know it would be much simpler to include it in my header file, but as I said, not allowed to change it.

```
struct Patient
{
    int priority;
    std::string name;

    Patient(int _priority, std::string _name)
    {
        priority = _priority;
        name = _name;
    }
};

class PatientQueue
{
  public:
    PatientQueue();
    ~PatientQueue();    // release memory and delete queue
    int size();
    bool isEmpty();
    void enqueue(int priority, std::string name);
    Patient* dequeue();     // returns pointer to patient record and removes from array
    void printList();                   // print the array
  private:
    void swap(int index1, int index2);  // swap the contents in the array
    Patient *waitlist[100];
    int lastIndex;
};
```

Comment: Just place `#include <string>` prior to the include statement for that header?

Comment: *but as I said, not allowed to change it*  -- "Here is a header file that fails to include the proper headers, has no include guards, but you're not supposed to change it" -- Wow, what an assignment -- your teacher must have a fragile ego.

Comment: No joke. We all told her that it needed to have #include <string> added to the header file, but she said "I have to encourage you to find out how including directives and libraries work, together with the order of compiling and linking files. Hint: you don't need to change the driver nor the header file." Jeez.

Answer (score 0):

Create a header file h1 that will include 
  string.h and bellow it your header.h

In your source file use h1 instead of the original header